# Using ShuffleJs in ionic project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to figure out how to use ShuffleJs with in an Ionic 3 project. I've used npm command to install it as directed here @ https://www.npmjs.com/package/shufflejs

Then I use the ES6 method for iniating the service/plugin. However, it is returning the error :

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Shuffle needs to be initialized with an element.
```

What I assume this method is telling me is that I haven't initialised it properly within the HTML. I've followed the guides and example code from ShuffleJs and I'm stuck. I'm very new to TypeScript and trying to rewire my brain from JavaScript.

**typescript for page:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import Shuffle from 'shufflejs';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-locator',
  templateUrl: 'locator.html'
})
export class LocatorPage {

  const shuffleInstance = new Shuffle(document.getElementById('grid'), {
  itemSelector: '.js-item',
  sizer: '.js-shuffle-sizer'
});

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

}
```

**HTML for page:**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Freshwater Macro invertebrates
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <div id="grid">
    <div class="js-item column">
      <div class="aspect aspect--16x9">
        <div class="aspect__inner"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/uploads/141310026617203b5980d/c86b8baa?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=600&amp;h=338&amp;fit=crop&amp;s=882e851a008e83b7a80d05bdc96aa817" obj.alt="obj.alt"/></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="js-item column">
      <div class="aspect aspect--16x9">
        <div class="aspect__inner"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/uploads/141310026617203b5980d/c86b8baa?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=600&amp;h=338&amp;fit=crop&amp;s=882e851a008e83b7a80d05bdc96aa817" obj.alt="obj.alt"/></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="js-item column">
      <div class="aspect aspect--16x9">
        <div class="aspect__inner"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/uploads/141310026617203b5980d/c86b8baa?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=600&amp;h=338&amp;fit=crop&amp;s=882e851a008e83b7a80d05bdc96aa817" obj.alt="obj.alt"/></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="js-item column">
      <div class="aspect aspect--16x9">
        <div class="aspect__inner"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/uploads/141310026617203b5980d/c86b8baa?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=600&amp;h=338&amp;fit=crop&amp;s=882e851a008e83b7a80d05bdc96aa817" obj.alt="obj.alt"/></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="js-item column">
      <div class="aspect aspect--16x9">
        <div class="aspect__inner"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/uploads/141310026617203b5980d/c86b8baa?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=600&amp;h=338&amp;fit=crop&amp;s=882e851a008e83b7a80d05bdc96aa817" obj.alt="obj.alt"/></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="js-item column">
      <div class="aspect aspect--16x9">
        <div class="aspect__inner"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/uploads/141310026617203b5980d/c86b8baa?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=600&amp;h=338&amp;fit=crop&amp;s=882e851a008e83b7a80d05bdc96aa817" obj.alt="obj.alt"/></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="js-item column">
      <div class="aspect aspect--16x9">
        <div class="aspect__inner"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/uploads/141310026617203b5980d/c86b8baa?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=600&amp;h=338&amp;fit=crop&amp;s=882e851a008e83b7a80d05bdc96aa817" obj.alt="obj.alt"/></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="js-item column">
      <div class="aspect aspect--16x9">
        <div class="aspect__inner"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/uploads/141310026617203b5980d/c86b8baa?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=600&amp;h=338&amp;fit=crop&amp;s=882e851a008e83b7a80d05bdc96aa817" obj.alt="obj.alt"/></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="js-item column">
      <div class="aspect aspect--16x9">
        <div class="aspect__inner"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/uploads/141310026617203b5980d/c86b8baa?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=600&amp;h=338&amp;fit=crop&amp;s=882e851a008e83b7a80d05bdc96aa817" obj.alt="obj.alt"/></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column my-sizer-element"></div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the `document.getElementById('grid')` does not find any element, because it is not loaded at the moment you trying to get it.

You can use the Ionic built in lifecycle events, for example `ionViewDidLoad()`.

```
const shuffleInstance;

ionViewDidLoad() {
    shuffleinstance = new Shuffle(document.getElementById('grid'), {
        itemSelector: '.js-item',
        sizer: '.js-shuffle-sizer'
    });
}
```

**Note**: I would recommend to keep the logic away from `constructor()` or outside of any functions, because inside of lifecycle hooks/events, you can control the execution much easier.

Here is the official documentation of the Ionic lifecycle event: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#lifecycle-events

You can also use the Angular lifecycle events in Ionic, as it is a part of Ionic: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: Of course! The ionViewDidLoad event, seems obvious now. I had to declare shuffleInstance as a 'var' as it was telling me that it was not defined:
var shuffleInstance = new Shuffle(document.getElementById('grid')

Comment: So your problem is fixed?

Comment: Thanks, I had to fix up some other areas of my code as well and now the behaviour is working as expected. I will select your answer as correct.